# how PropertyDescriptor class works in java

Tags: java

I want to map resultSet to my entity. So I wrote a generic class like below . I map every single row to my entity and add that entity into a list. But at the result all of the entities that are in the list are the same and the value of that entity is the first record of the database.

Here is my code:

```
public class ResultSetMapperImpl<T> implements ResultSetMapper<T> {

  @Override
  public List<T> mapResultSetToEntity(ResultSet resultSet, T t)
  throws IntrospectionException, SQLException, InvocationTargetException,
      IllegalAccessException {

Field[] fields = t.getClass().getDeclaredFields();
List<T> result = new ArrayList<>();
while (resultSet.next()) {

  Object object = null;
  for (int j = 0; j < fields.length; j++) {

    if (fields[j].getType().getSimpleName().equalsIgnoreCase("long")) {
      object = resultSet.getLong(j + 1);
    } else if (fields[j].getType().getSimpleName().equalsIgnoreCase("int")) {
      object = resultSet.getInt(j + 1);
    } else if (fields[j].getType().getSimpleName().equalsIgnoreCase("Date")) {
      object = resultSet.getDate(j + 1);
    } else if (fields[j].getType().getSimpleName().equalsIgnoreCase("String")) {
      object = resultSet.getString(j + 1);
    } else if (fields[j].getType().getSimpleName().equalsIgnoreCase("timestamp")) {
      object = resultSet.getTimestamp(j + 1);
    } else if (fields[j].getType().getSimpleName().equalsIgnoreCase("time")) {
      object = resultSet.getTime(j + 1);
    }
    new PropertyDescriptor(fields[j].getName(), t.getClass())
        .getWriteMethod()
        .invoke(t, object);
  }
  result.add(t);
}

return result;
  }
}
```

Comment: Don’t use PropertyDescriptor for this.  Just use `fields[j].set(t, object)`.  That said, I think you’ll eventually find that it’s not worth the trouble and complexity.  Just make a new non-reflective method for setting the properties of each of your data types from a ResultSet.  Even if you have thirty or fifty data types, it’s easier in the long run.  **CAUTION:** You are adding the *same object* (`t`) to your List over and over, so you’ll have many copies of the same data!  You must make a new object for each result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don’t use PropertyDescriptor for this.  Just use `fields[j].set(t, object)`.

That said, you’ll eventually find that this is not a good approach.  It’s not worth the trouble and complexity.  Just make a new non-reflective method for setting the properties of each of your data types from a ResultSet.  Even if you have thirty or fifty data types, it’s easier in the long run.

For example:

```
public List<Person> mapResultSetToPersons(ResultSet resultSet)
throws SQLException {
    List<Person> result = new ArrayList<>();
    while (resultSet.next()) {
        Person person = new Person();

        person.setFirstName(resultSet.getString("firstName"));
        person.setLastName(resultSet.getString("lastName"));
        person.setDateOfBirth(resultSet.getDate("dateOfBirth"));
        person.setAddress(resultSet.getString("address"));

        result.add(person);
    }
    return result;
}
```

**CAUTION:**  You are currently adding the *same object* (`t`) to your List over and over.  This means you will end up with multiple copies of the same data!

You need to make a new object for each ResultSet row.  If you insist on using reflection, you can do it by taking a class argument instead of a single object:

```
public List<T> mapResultSetToEntity(ResultSet resultSet, Class<T> resultType)
throws SQLException,
       ReflectiveOperationException {

    // ...

    while (resultSet.next()) {
        T t = resultType.getConstructor().newInstance();

        for (int j = 0; j < fields.length; j++) {
            // ...
        }

        result.add(t);
    }
}
```

Or, you could pass the constructor itself as a [Supplier](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/docs/api/java.base/java/util/function/Supplier.html):

```
public List<T> mapResultSetToEntity(ResultSet resultSet, Supplier<T> constructor)
throws SQLException,
       ReflectiveOperationException {

    // ...

    while (resultSet.next()) {
        T t = constructor.get();

        for (int j = 0; j < fields.length; j++) {
            // ...
        }

        result.add(t);
    }
}
```

And invocation of that method might look like:

```
List<Person> persons = mapResultSetToEntity(resultSet, Person::new);
```